# Web API não aceita parâmetros no construtor com Autofac

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api

Criei uma API para consultar cliente, essa é minha configuração:

```
public static class AutofacWebapiConfig
{
    public static IContainer Container;

    public static void Initialize(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        Initialize(config, RegisterServices(new ContainerBuilder()));
    }

    public static void Initialize(HttpConfiguration config, IContainer container)
    {
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }

    private static IContainer RegisterServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        #region Application

        builder.RegisterType<ClienteAppService>().As<IClienteAppService>().InstancePerRequest();

        #endregion Application

        #region Domain Services

        #region

        builder.RegisterType<ClienteService>().As<IClienteService>().InstancePerRequest();

        #endregion

        #endregion Domain Services

        #region Data

        #region Context

        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<SessionFactory>().As<ISessionFactory>().InstancePerRequest();

        #endregion Context

        #region Repositories

        #region Pessoas

        builder.RegisterType<ClienteRepository>().As<IClienteRepository>().InstancePerRequest();

        #endregion

        #endregion Repositories

        #endregion Data

        Container = builder.Build();
        return Container;
    }
}

public class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        // Configurar o AutoFac  
        AutofacWebapiConfig.Initialize(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    }
}
```

**Global.asax**

```
  protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        Bootstrapper.Run();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

**ClienteController**

```
public class ClienteController : ApiController
{
    public readonly IClienteAppService _clienteAppService;

    public ClienteController(IClienteAppService clienteAppService)
    {
        _clienteAppService = clienteAppService;
    }

    // GET: api/Cliente/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        var cliente = _clienteAppService.GetCliente(id);
        return "value";
    }

    }
}
```

Quando incio minha app e tento consultar um cliente, me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Ocorreu um erro.  Ocorreu
>   um erro ao tentar criar um controlador do tipo 'ClienteController'.
>   Verifique se o controlador tem um construtor público sem parâmetros.
>   
>   System.InvalidOperationException
>    em
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType) em
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage
>   request) em
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()
>     Ocorreu um erro.
>    O tipo 'IMP.Api.Controllers.ClienteController' não
>   tem um construtor padrão 
>   System.ArgumentException 
>   em System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type) em
>   System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type
>   instanceType) em
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator) em
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)

Diz que preciso ter um construtor publico para funcionar, mas se eu criar um construtor público como irei fazer para injetar no construtor minha interface?...

Comment: Já tentou criar um construtor público sem parâmetros pra ver se o erro persiste?

Comment: @perozzo Construtor sem parâmetros não gera erro, mas minha interface fica null...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao analisar a [`documentação`](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html), vi que você pulou uma etapa importante, registrar as Controllers.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

  // Get your HttpConfiguration.
  var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

  // Register your Web API controllers.
  builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

  // OPTIONAL: Register the Autofac filter provider.
  builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);

  // OPTIONAL: Register the Autofac model binder provider.
  builder.RegisterWebApiModelBinderProvider();

  // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
  var container = builder.Build();
  config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
}
```